# Perl script to copy logs with timestamp for every hour and paste into different file

Tags: perl, file, copy

First of all, I'm very new to programming and so would need your help in writing a perl script to do the following on windows.

I have a big log file with timestamp (1gb) and its difficult to read the logs as it takes a lot of time to open. so my requirement is to copy the logs from the bigger log file for the last one hour and paste it to another file and then copy the next 1 hr of data to different file(so we will have 24 files for a day). The next day the data in these files needs to be over written or delete & create a new file.

Sample log :

```
09092016-00:02:00,..................
09092016-00:02:08,..................
09092016-00:02:15,..................
09092016-00:02:18,..................
```

Please help me with this and thanks for your help in advance.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to use the split command to split the files into manageable sizes.

```
split -l 1000 logfile
```

Will split your logfile into smaller files of 1000 lines each.
You can then just use grep to find the files that contain the day you need.

```
grep 09092016 logfile*
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply john..i had tried this already..but i'd like to split the logs per hour so its easier to check the log based on timestamp which i'm not aware of..pls let me know if there is different solution..Thanks again..!!!

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
logfile="./log"
while read -r d m y h; do
    grep "^$d$m$y-$h" "$logfile" > "partial-${y}${m}{$d}-${h}.log"
done < <(sed -n 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)-\(..\)\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4/p' "$logfile" | sort -u)
```

easy, but **not** efficient. It reads the whole big logfile 25x for the split. (1x for gathering the existing `ddmmyyyy-hh` lines in the log, and again for every different found date-hour.)